# Programmtically add image to custom image field User

Tags: 7, users, media

I can't figure out how to add image to a custom image field on a sepcific user.

```
    $f = file_save_data($user['thumbnailphoto'][0], 'private://profile/'. $data['name'] .'.jpg', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    $fid = $f->fid;

    //Add to virtual map 'Profile images'
    $file_entity = file_load($fid);
    $file_entity->status = 1;
    $file_entity->field_folder['und'][0]['tid'] = 180;
    file_save($file_entity);

    $user = user_load(334);

    $details['field_profile_picture'] = array(
                                        'und' => array( 
                                            0 => array(
                                            'fid' => $fid,
    )));

    $u = user_save($user, $details);
```

But nothing get saved? Field_profile_picture is just an image field.

Thx!

Comment: Probably not causing your problem, but you should never hardcode in 'und' for language. Instead use the defined constant, `LANGUAGE_UNDEFINED` or a `$language` variable.

Comment: Have you tried using Devel and `dpm` after every `file_save`, `user_load`, `user_save` call to be sure the actions are being performed?

Comment: I'll try ;). Thx!

Comment: LANGUAGE_UNDEFINED did the trick, thx!

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use [system_retrieve_file()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7)

> **system_retrieve_file** : This function will download a file from a remote source, copy it from temp to a specified destination and optionally save it to
>   the file_managed table if you want it to be managed.

```
  $usr_info = user_load(334); //load user object
  if (!empty($usr_info)) {//assign only if user exist
    $image_url = 'http://g-raph.be/sites/all/themes/g_raph_/images/image03.jpg'; //image URL to save. If image already saved in the drupal system then get the file ID(fid)
    //I have used picture folder to store images using image field settings
    $file_info = system_retrieve_file($image_url, 'public://pictures/', TRUE, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE); //storing image inside picture folder
    if ($file_info->fid) {//if fid exist then image is saved from URL.
      //$usr_info->picture = file_load($file_info->fid); //for default profile pic
      $usr_info->field_profile_picture[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'] = $file_info->fid; //for custom profile pic
    }
    user_save($usr_info);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not answer to my question, the question would be: How to download a file from a remote source and save it to a custom user field :p. But thx annyway ;)

Comment: Your are trying to assign a profile picture to a particular user right?

Comment: What is the value of `$user['thumbnailphoto'][0]`?

Comment: i should have called it $image, its an variable containing the image :) data. But it's not important, the picture get's saved correctly, the fid is just not saved on the custom field.

Comment: If **details** is an object then try to use : `$details->field_profile_picture['LANGUAGE_NONE'][0]['fid'] = $fid;`. Can you provide me more details on **$details** variable/object?

Comment: Details isn't an object, its een array, the array wich is passed to user_save.
 
LANGUAGE_UNDEFINED did the trick.